# Excel Solver run time - setting up vs actively solving

Tags: excel, nonlinear-optimization, vba

I am using VBA for Solver Add-In optimization because I need to iterate through multiple objective functions and constraints.

Optimization is taking longer than expected due to the time spent in the "Setting Up Problem..." step (displayed in the status bar), not the time spent actively solving the problem. This is problematic because I am solving many independent problems.

Running a manual Solver instance without VBA code sets up far faster. What variables affect Solver set up time and how can this time be reduced?

VBA Code:

```
Sub MinimizeDiff()

     SolverReset

     SolverOk SetCell:="$K$3", MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:="$C$3:$E$3", Engine:=3

     SolverAdd CellRef:="$K$3", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
     SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$3", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$F$3"
     SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$3", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$F$3"
     SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$3", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$F$3"
     SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$3:$E$3", Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
     SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$3:$E$3", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"

     SolverOptions MaxTime:=240, Iterations:=100, Precision:=0.000001, AssumeLinear:=False, StepThru:=False, _
          Estimates:=2, Derivatives:=1, SearchOption:=1, IntTolerance:=0, Scaling:=False, Convergence:=0.01, _
          AssumeNonNeg:=True, MaxTimeNoImp:=30

     SolverSolve

End Sub
```

Comment: You could always try `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start of the macro and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True' at the end. Perhaps also experiment with setting `Application.Calculate = xlManual` at the start and `xlAutomatic` at the end.

Comment: @johncoleman I experimented with this but it did not seem to decrease setup time. I suspect that solver is storing the formulas and calculations for all cells that are linked to the objective cell prior to solving the problem and this is taking a long time due to the complexity of my spreadsheet.

Comment: If the dimensions of the objective function and constraints are the same but only the coefficients are different, you could just modify the coefficients in the spreadsheet and rerun the model without needing to repeatedly set up the model. Without knowing the details of what you are doing it is hard to say more.